# Datatypes, data shapes, and pad_sequences

Tags: python, keras

I cannot understand the error message I receive in this code. The part with `x_train` is from a working example showing how to use LSTM in Keras.

The part with `mytrain` is just an example I was playing with to understand the various functions.

As you can see from the messages, `x_train` and `mytrain` have the same type and shape.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.datasets import imdb
import numpy as np

max_features = 80
maxlen = 5

# from the example
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print('x_train type: ', type(x_train))
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)

# my test code
mytrain = np.ones_like(x_train)
print('mytrain type:', type(mytrain))
print('mytrain shape:', mytrain.shape)
mytrain2 = sequence.pad_sequences(mytrain, maxlen=maxlen)
```

Output:

```
D:\python\python.exe D:/workspace/YYYY/test/test_sequences.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
x_train type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
x_train shape: (25000,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workspace/YYYY/test/test_sequences.py", line 22, in <module>
    mytrain2 = sequence.pad_sequences(mytrain, maxlen=10)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\sequence.py", line 42, in pad_sequences
    'Found non-iterable: ' + str(x))
mytrain type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: 1
mytrain shape: (25000,)
```

It works if I use, for example, `mytrain = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3]])` (list of iterables), but I cannot understand what the different is between `x_train` and `mytrain` in the previous code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**

When you print `x_train` you get:

```
[ [1, 14, 22, 16, 43, 2, 2, 2, 2, 65, 2, 2, 66, 2, 4, 2, 36, 2, 5, 25, 2, 43, 2, 2, 50, 2, 2, 9, 35, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 39, 4, 2, 2, 2, 17, 2, 38, 13, 2, 4, 2, 50, 16, 6, 2, 2, 19, 14, 22, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 22, 71, 2, 12, 16, 43, 2, 38, 76, 15, 13, 2, 4, 22, 17, 2, 17, 12, 16, 2, 18, 2, 5, 62, 2, 12, 8, 2, 8, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 16, 2, 66, 2, 33, 4, 2, 12, 16, 38, 2, 5, 25, 2, 51, 36, 2, 48, 25, 2, 33, 6, 22, 12, 2, 28, 77, 52, 5, 14, 2, 16, 2, 2, 8, 4, 2, 2, 2, 15, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 5, 2, 36, 71, 43, 2, 2, 26, 2, 2, 46, 7, 4, 2, 2, 13, 2, 2, 4, 2, 15, 2, 2, 32, 2, 56, 26, 2, 6, 2, 2, 18, 4, 2, 22, 21, 2, 2, 26, 2, 5, 2, 30, 2, 18, 51, 36, 28, 2, 2, 25, 2, 4, 2, 65, 16, 38, 2, 2, 12, 16, 2, 5, 16, 2, 2, 2, 32, 15, 16, 2, 19, 2, 32]
 ...,
 [1, 17, 6, 2, 2, 7, 4, 2, 22, 45, 2, 8, 2, 14, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 39, 14, 2, 4, 2, 9, 2, 50, 2, 12, 47, 4, 2, 5, 2, 7, 38, 2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 2, 2, 9, 24, 6, 78, 2, 17, 2, 2, 21, 27, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 7, 4, 2, 42, 2, 2, 35, 2, 2, 29, 2, 27, 2, 8, 2, 12, 2, 21, 2, 2, 9, 6, 66, 78, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 2, 21, 60, 27, 2, 9, 43, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 12, 2, 40, 4, 2, 20, 12, 16, 5, 2, 2, 72, 7, 51, 6, 2, 22, 4, 2, 2, 9]]
```

Where each element is a list. While `mytrain` is:

```
[1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
```

Which is just a list of integers.

**SOLUTION:**

This should give you what you need:

```
mytrain = []
for i in range(0,x_train.shape[0]):
    mytrain.append(np.ones(len(x_train[i])))
mytrain = np.asarray(mytrain)
```

Indeed:

```
('x_train type: ', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)
('x_train shape:', (25000,))
('mytrain type:', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)
('mytrain shape:', (25000,))
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that using a list `mytrain = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3]])` it was ok. However, `print('mytrain shape:', mytrain.shape)` gives `mytrain shape: (1, 3)`, while `x_train` is `(N, )`. I am still confused.

Comment: Yes, because now mytrain is an array with arrays as elements, and, in a nutshell, is thus considered a 2D array. X_train is an array with lists as elements, and is considered a 1D array.

If you try and print x_train[0].shape it will tell you that you can't get a list's shape, because element #0 of x_train is indeed a list. If you print mytrain[0].shape you get (3,), because the element is an array. Array of arrays = 2D array.

Comment: Thank you. So basically, it depends on the size of the lists in the array: if they all have the same size, then it is considered a 2D array. Quite obvious when you realize it, but a bit obscure when you first read about the shape.

Comment: No it depends on the type! An array with arrays inside (mytrain) is a 2D array. An array with lists inside (x_train) is a 1D array where each element is a list. mytrain = np.array ; mytrain[0] = np.array ; x_train = np.array ; x_train[0] = list

Answer (score 2):

I just simply put `mytrain` in squared bracket `[]` and it solves the issue

```
# my test code
mytrain = np.ones_like(x_train)
print('mytrain type:', type(mytrain))
print('mytrain shape:', mytrain.shape)
mytrain2 = sequence.pad_sequences([mytrain], maxlen=maxlen)
```